# What makes ValueType class Special?

Tags: c#, inheritance, compiler-errors

When I trying to define a class which inherits from `System.ValueType` or `System.Enum` class, I'm getting an error:

```
Cannot derive from special class System.ValueType
```

I understand that error but what I couldn't understand is what makes `ValueType` class **special**? I mean there is no keyword (like `sealed`) or attribute to specify that this class can not be inherited.`ValueType` has two attributes, `Serializable` and `ComVisible` but none of them is relevant with that case.The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says:

> Although ValueType is the implicit base class for value types, **you cannot create a class that inherits from ValueType directly.** Instead, individual compilers provide a language keyword or construct (such as struct in C# and Structure…End Structure in Visual Basic) to support the creation of value types.

But it doesn't answer my question.So my question is how the compiler is informed in this case? Does the compiler directly check whether the class is `ValueType` or `Enum` when I try to create a class that inherit from a class?

Edit: Also all structs `implicitly` inherit from `ValueType`, but `Enum` class **Explicitly** inherit from `ValueType`,so how is that working? How the compiler figure out this situation,   all of this are hard coded by compiler?

Comment: Yes, I would expect rules like that (the same applies to `Delegate`) to be *hardcoded* in compilers code, just to match language specification.

Comment: yes,it might be right.But as far as I know,attributes and preprocessor directives using in these cases to inform the compiler.Isn't that more appropriate that create an attribute to specify that this class is a special and cannot be inherited instead of hard coding?

Comment: @Selman22 - Based on previous answers I've seen from key members of the C# team on SO, it sounds as though the bindings to these integral types are hard-coded into the compiler. Inheritance hierarchies are an integral part of the C# language design and using attributes or otherwise to describe base-inheritance type relationships would be counter-intuitive.

Comment: @M.Babcock I understand your point.I'm waiting maybe someone could explain that reason clearly.I'm also wonder Enum class is inherit from ValueType,is that hard-coded too by the compiler ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> I understand that error but what I couldn't understand is what makes ValueType class special?

The class is *documented* as being special. That's what makes it special.

> how the compiler is informed in this case?

The compiler writers read the documentation before they write the compiler.

> Does the compiler directly check whether the class is ValueType or Enum when I try to create a class that inherit from a class?

Yes.

> Also all structs implicitly inherit from ValueType, but Enum class Explicitly inherit from ValueType, so how is that working?

It's working pretty well.

> Are all of these special cases hard coded into the compiler?

Yes.

> Isn't it more appropriate to create an attribute to specify that this class is special and cannot be inherited instead of hard coding?

No, it's not. That would imply that a third party could also make a special type that needed special handling by the compiler when inherited from. How would the third party then modify the compiler to implement those rules?

Comment: Thank you for your answer I understand now.And I thought documentation writing according to compiler,but apparently it was not. :)

Comment: @EricLippert this came to mind, you said : `That would imply that a third party could also make a special type that needed special handling by the compiler when inherited from.` But what happens if you define an `internal attiribute` and use it in ValueType ? other people can't use that attribute because it's internal?

Comment: @Selman22: An internal type is an implementation detail. Why do you care what the implementation details of the compiler are? Why would inventing a new attribute and making sure that attribute is on the four special types (ValueType, Enum, Delegate and MulticastDelegate) be any easier than simply having a list that contains the words "ValueType, Enum, Delegate, MulticastDelegate"?

Comment: @EricLippert, I don't care just curiosity

Comment: @EricLippert  I thought that is a standart or rule(specify things like that with attributes) and you are following these standarts when you writing the compiler.but apparently you are choosing the simpler version on special cases :)

Comment: @Selman22: The framework design guidelines are about the public surface area of a set of classes, not about its implementation details.

Answer (score 3):

[System.ValueType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a special handled class for the compiler, used to **annotate** the value types. It is used differently by the compiler, because **value type objects are handled differently than reference type objects**. I suppose [this series of blog posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/theoy/archive/2005/06/24/valueref.aspx) could provide some clarification about the differences betweebn value and reference types.   [This MSDN post describes the common cases of value reference types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) so that you could categorize each type easily.

The answer to your question, is in the .NET [Common Type System](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). **If you want to create your own value type class, I would suggest to create a structure**. Copying from (Common TYpe System, Structures reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcx1eb1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Structures):

> A structure is a value type that derives implicitly from `System.ValueType`, which in turn is derived from `System.Object`. ...  In the .NET Framework class library, all primitive data types (`Boolean`, `Byte,` Char, `DateTime`, `Decimal`, `Double`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `SByte`, `Single`, `UInt16`, `UInt32`, and `UInt64`) are defined as structures.
>
> Like classes, structures define both data (the fields of the structure) and the operations that can be performed on that data (the methods of the structure). ...
>
> Value types also differ from classes in several respects. First, although they **implicitly inherit from `System.ValueType`**, they **cannot directly inherit from any type**. Similarly, **all value types are sealed, which means that no other type can be derived from them**. ...
>
> For each value type, the common language runtime supplies a corresponding **boxed type**, which is a class that has the same state and behavior as the value type. ... **When you define a value type, you are defining both the boxed and the unboxed type**.

Hope I helped!

Comment: Thanks, not exactly answering my question but good references :) I actually want to know how is perfomring that **special handling process**.I'm gonna read these blog posts thanks again.

Comment: I know. I just don't have the necessary insights. If you find it, please post it here.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft does not publish its C# compiler source code, so we can only guess the check is embedded at compiler level.

Mono's C# compiler performs this kind of check at compile time, which you can see around line 2790 in `Class.ResolveBaseTypes` method,

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/mcs/class.cs

Comment: good point,you right.There should be a code something like this in the c# compiler.