# How does the compiler recognise Nullable<T> to be a 'special type'?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, clr, nullable

`Nullable<T>` is a struct that has the following definition:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

where `struct` is a type constraint so that T is constrained to (according to the spec §4.4.4):

- struct type or enum type
- not a nullable type.

Looking in the source for `Nullable<T>` there are no special attributes (expect for `[Serializable]`), so how does the compiler can recognise it as a "nullable type"?

In response to the comments below:

`int` is an *alias* for `Int32`:

> (§4.1.4) simple types are identified through reserved words, but these
>   reserved words are simply **aliases** for predefined struct types in the
>   System namespace

`T?` is *shorthand* for `Nullable<T>`:

> (§4.1.10) - A nullable type is written T?, where T is the underlying
>   type. This syntax is **shorthand** for System.Nullable, and the two
>   forms can be used interchangeably.

This seems to be a distinct difference which isn't reflected below.

So how does the compiler recognise a simple struct (with no special code) as a "nullable type", struct name?

Comment: Well it's a special type; this is also why the compiler understands "int?" as "Nullable<int>".

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2503832/1324810) helpful

Comment: @ken2k - I don't agree, that's simply a type alias so the compiler will simply translate `int?` into `Nullable<int>` during compilation

Comment: @m.edmondson I would say it's not an alias but a syntatic-sugar that is language-dependent. Also, Nullable has specific boxing capabilities that can't normally be defined.

Comment: The compiler has to do all kinds of special handling for different types. I'd imagine the compiler "recognizes" `Nullable<T>` in a similar way to the way it recognizes e.g. `Int32`.

Comment: The C# compiler certainly has intimate knowledge of Nullables.  It for example allows them with the ?? operator and permits lifted conversion operators on them.  It is not very clear what particular aspect you are asking about.

Comment: This seems like similar of my old question about `ValueType` class.See: [What makes ValueType class Special?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213708/what-makes-valuetype-class-special)

Comment: @Selman22 - I agree this question is more about "special types" in general.  Eric's response of `Are all of these special cases hard coded into the compiler? Yes.` probably answers this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based off of the [Shared Source CLI 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917), `Nullable<T>` is made "special" via the `PREDEFTYPEDEF` macro, which takes the name "`System.Nullable`" and maps it to the attribute `PT_G_OPTIONAL` which is checked throughout the rest of the compiler.

With regards to the aliases of `int` → `System.Int32` et al., see the "nice name" column.

From `sscli20\csharp\inc\predeftype.h`:

```
//         id            full type name       required  simple     numer    AggKind  fund type   elementtype,      nice name,    zero, quasi simple numer, attribute arg size serialization type,  predef attribute, arity, in mscorlib)
PREDEFTYPEDEF(PT_BYTE,   "System.Byte",         1,            1,      1,     Struct,   FT_U1,   ELEMENT_TYPE_U1,      L"byte",      0,                 0,      1,      SERIALIZATION_TYPE_U1,      PA_COUNT, 0, 1)
PREDEFTYPEDEF(PT_SHORT,  "System.Int16",        1,            1,      1,     Struct,   FT_I2,   ELEMENT_TYPE_I2,      L"short",     0,                 0,      2,      SERIALIZATION_TYPE_I2,      PA_COUNT, 0, 1)
PREDEFTYPEDEF(PT_INT,    "System.Int32",        1,            1,      1,     Struct,   FT_I4,   ELEMENT_TYPE_I4,      L"int",       0,                 0,      4,      SERIALIZATION_TYPE_I4,      PA_COUNT, 0, 1)
PREDEFTYPEDEF(PT_LONG,   "System.Int64",        1,            1,      1,     Struct,   FT_I8,   ELEMENT_TYPE_I8,      L"long",      &longZero,         0,      8,      SERIALIZATION_TYPE_I8,      PA_COUNT, 0, 1)
// ... snip ...
// Nullable<T>
PREDEFTYPEDEF(PT_G_OPTIONAL, "System.Nullable",  0,     0,     0,   Struct,   FT_STRUCT,  ELEMENT_TYPE_END,      NULL,          0,                 0,      0,      0,                          PA_COUNT, 1, 1)
```

Then its used elsewhere like this:

From `sscli20\csharp\sccomp\nullable.cpp`:

```
/***************************************************************************************************
    Return true iff the method is the nullable ctor taking one parameter.
***************************************************************************************************/
bool FUNCBREC::IsNubCtor(METHSYM * meth)
{
    return meth && meth->getClass()->isPredefAgg(PT_G_OPTIONAL) && meth->params->size == 1 &&
        meth->params->Item(0)->isTYVARSYM() && meth->isCtor();
}
```

For those reading this question, you are probably the target audience for [Shared Source CLI 2.0 Internals](http://callvirt.net/blog/files/Shared%20Source%20CLI%202.0%20Internals.pdf), which was released as a free e-book.

Comment: Wow! Amazing answer.  So the short answer is indeed that the hardcoded struct name is what identifies `System.Nullable` as special?